# JSON Schema if/then/else for property that can be an object or null based on another properties value

Tags: postman, jsonschema, ajv

I have a property that will be an object or null based on the value of another property. I'm trying to add this new check to my schema using an if/then/else. This is for AJV validation in Postman if that's pertinent .

For example, this sample payload

```js
{
  "topObj": {
    "subItem1": "2021-09-12",
    "subItem2": "2021-09-21",
    "ineligibleReason": "",
    "myObject": {
      "subObject1": true,
      "subObject2": ""
    }
  }
}
```

If ineligibleReason is an empty string then `subObject` should be an object. If ineligibleReason isn't an empty string then `subObject` should be null as in this table:

| ineligibleReason value | myObject value | schema valid? |
| --- | --- | --- |
| "" | object | true |
| "" | null | false |
| "any value" | null | true |
| "any value" | object | false |

Here's what I have so far. jsonschema.dev thinks it's a valid schema but when I add a value to ineligibleReason in the payload (keeping myObject as an object) it still says the JSON payload is valid!

```js
{
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "topObj": {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "subItem1":         { "type": "string" },
        "subItem2":         { "type": "string" },
        "ineligibleReason": { "type": "string" },
        "myObject":         { "type": ["object", "null"] }
      }
    }
  },
  "required": ["topObj"],
  "additionalProperties": false,
  
  "if": {
    "properties": { "topObj.ineligibleReason": { "const": "" } }
  },
  "then": {
    "properties": { 
      "topObj.myObject": {
        "type": "object",
        "properties": {
          "subObject1": { "type": "boolean" },
          "subObject2": { "type": "string"  }
        },
        "required": ["subObject1", "subObject2"],
        "additionalProperties": false
      }
    }
  },
  "else" : {
    "properties": { "myObject": { "type": "null" } }
  }
  
}
```

I have this in [jsonschema.dev](https://jsonschema.dev/s/3W1ax) but it gives Schema Error `"/properties/required" should be object,boolean`.
My basic schemas are working but I'm not sure how to add this conditional validation based on another properties value.

**Update 1** I updated the schema and it's now parses as valid. However the payload validates when ineligibleReason has a value and myObject is an object instead of being null.

**Update 2** I [updated the schema](https://jsonschema.dev/s/Z5M2w) again, moving the if/then/else to the bottom (no longer "inline"). The schema definition parses as valid, however the payload validates successfully irrespective of the invalid situations (ineligibleReason has a value and myObject is an object instead of being null).

How do I get the if/then/else to validate my `subObject` property correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer per Ryan Miller on json-schema Slack. A slightly different tack then I was trying but simpler and works!

```
{
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "topObj": {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "subItem1":         { "type": "string" },
        "subItem2":         { "type": "string" },
        "ineligibleReason": { "type": "string" },
        "myObject":         {
          "type": ["object", "null"],
          "$comment": "'properties', 'required', and 'additionalProperties' only make assertions when the instance is an object.",
          "properties": {
            "subObject1": { "type": "boolean" },
            "subObject2": { "type": "string"  }
          },
          "required": ["subObject1", "subObject2"],
          "additionalProperties": false
        }
      },
      "required": ["subItem1", "subItem2", "ineligibleReason", "myObject"],
      "additionalProperties": false,
      "if": {
        "$comment": "Is an ineligibleReason defined?",
        "properties": {
          "ineligibleReason": {"minLength": 1}
        }
      },
      "then": {
        "$comment": "Then 'myObject' must be null.",
        "properties": {
          "myObject": {"type": "null"}
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "required": ["topObj"],
  "additionalProperties": false
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The error message is pointing to the problem. /properties/required is declaring a property named "required", and then the value under that needs to be a schema (object, or boolean). So you need to lift that "required" to be adjacent to "properties", rather than beneath it.

Comment: I adjusted my schema definition, moving the last required/additionalProperties down one level. I also removed the required/additionalProperties from topObj as it was causing schema errors. I'll fix that after I get the if/then/else working.

Even though the schema def parses successfully it's not validating per the truth table I added to the problem definition.

Comment: @Jim You need to move the `if`/`then`/`else` keywords out of `properties` as well.

Comment: @JasonDesrosiers I moved it out of the properties. I was thinking of the conditional logically belonged in-line. The schema definition seems to be valid but invalid payloads validate successfully. Here's an [example of an invalid payload passing validation](https://jsonschema.dev/s/Z5M2w).

Comment: @Jim Your next problem is that you can't use dot notation in property names. You can use dots, but they are just part of the property name. You need to express it in long form like `properties { topObj: { properties: { ineligibleReason: { const: "" } } } }`.